SSIS Send Mail Task Editor Doesn't Recognize Any Expressions
I'm trying to set up an SSIS package to send emails. I've set up a parameter to pass into the ToLine but when I click on the Send Mail Task Properties --> Expressions it does not recognize the parameter. In fact, it doesn't recognize anything -- I can click on one of the canned functions and it doesn't recognize any of them either.
Below is a picture of what I'm seeing. As mentioned I'm creating the parameters, building and rebuilding the package, and saving it. Then I will select the Send Mail Task Editor and edit the Expressions in it's properties.  Under Property I'm selecting ToLine and then clicking the ellipses to select my newly created parameter.  When I double click on it, it does not move it down into the expression area.  I have also tried to select one of the built-in functions just to see if it would work and I get the same result.  When I click the Evaluation Expression button it says there's nothing to evaluation, which is correct.  I've also tried closing my solution and reopening it, and creating a completely new package, and I get the same results.  Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing incorrect?
enter image description here
